# How to set Checkboxes for other tables to enabled if one table is true?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, checkbox

I have a table that is going through a validation with ajax, and the result returned is true, I have also set up a global flag where if the validation of that table is true, then the checkboxes for all the other tables should be enabled as well but for some reason its not working, and I dont know why. The table going through the validation is working 'tabCSite1' and 'tabCEquip1', where the checkboxes for it are enabled but for the other typetables its not working. Here is the code:

```
    function getDetailsCheckJob(data, typetable, checkboxname,t) {
    
    var tblC = document.getElementById(typetable);
    for (var i = tblC.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        tblC.deleteRow(i);
    }

    Row = data.split('[');

    var tab = document.getElementById(typetable);
    var valid_asb = false;
    var valid_FTTH = false;
    var tabCSite1Valid = false;

    for (var p = 0; p < Row.length - 1; p++) {
        var row = tab.insertRow(p + 1);

        row.style.background = "#e8eef4";
        row.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";

        splitData = Row[p + 1].split('|');
        

        if (splitData[0] == "Y") {
            row.insertCell(0);
            tab.rows[p + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"valueZ\" name=\"" + checkboxname + "\" value=\"" + splitData[1] + "\" checked/>"; //checked
        }
        else if (splitData[0] == "N") {
            row.insertCell(0);
            tab.rows[p + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"valueZ\" name=\"" + checkboxname + "\" value=\"" + splitData[1] + "\"/>";
        }
      
       if (typetable == "tabCEquip1") {
           checkValidation(splitData[2], splitData[28], splitData[29], t, jobID, function (resp) {

               valid_asb = resp.isASBExist;
               valid_FTTH = resp.isFTTHExist;
           });
        }

        else if (typetable == "tabCSite1") {

        checkValidation(splitData[2], splitData[23], splitData[29], t, jobID,function (resp) {
            valid_asb = resp.isASBExist;
            valid_FTTH = resp.isFTTHExist;
            tabCSite1Valid = valid_FTTH; // Update the global flag here
            console.log('tabCSite1Valid inside: ', tabCSite1Valid);
        });
        }

        var splitDatalen = splitData.length;

        if (typetable == "tabCEquip1" || typetable == "tabCSite1") {
            splitDatalen = splitDatalen - 3;
        }
        else {
            splitDatalen = splitDatalen - 1;
        }

        for (var i = 1; i < splitDatalen; i++) {

            console.log('tabCSite1Valid inside other one: ', tabCSite1Valid);
            //alert(splitData.length);
            row.insertCell(i);
            styleData = splitData[i + 1];
                if (typetable == "tabCEquip1" || typetable == "tabCSite1" || typetable == "tabCSBoundary1" || typetable == "tabLPcomm1" || typetable == "tabAddCardSplit1" || typetable == "tabDelEquip1" || typetable == "tabDelPath1" || typetable == "tabDelSB1" || typetable == "tabCPathConsumer1" || typetable == "tabCreateServiceOLT1") {
                    if (tabCSite1Valid == false) {
                        tab.rows[p + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"valueZ\" name=\"" + checkboxname + "\" value=\"" + splitData[1] + "\" disabled/>";
                        styleData = "<span style='color: red'>" + splitData[i + 1] + "</span>";
                        console.log('Activated at FTTH');
                    }
                if (splitData[3] != "ASB" && valid_asb == true) { //else && valid_FTTH == false
                    tab.rows[p + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"valueZ\" name=\"" + checkboxname + "\" value=\"" + splitData[1] + "\" disabled/>";
                    styleData = "<span style='color: red'>" + splitData[i + 1] + "</span>";
                    console.log('Activated at ASB');
                }
            }
            tab.rows[p + 1].cells[i].innerHTML = styleData;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is the for loop for the last one, the 'tabCSite1Valid' is true for the tables tabCEquip1 and tabCSite1. I even set it to global and yet its still not being true for all the other tables. Where am I going wrong and how to fix it?

As can be seen in the picture, the checkbox is supposed to be enabled because the 'tabCSite1Valid' is true but instead its false

[image]

Comment: Can I see your disign? for example png or total app code

Comment: Hello, I have added a picture

Answer (score 0):

The `for loop` that contains the conditional checks for `tabCSite1Valid` is likely executing before the `checkValidation` has finished processing. This would mean that `tabCSite1Valid` is still `false` when the `loop` is checking its value, even though it gets updated to `true` later on.

Maybe it will solve your problem when you move the `loop` inside the callback function of the `checkValidation`.

Modified code in that part;

```
if (typetable == "tabCSite1") {
   checkValidation(splitData[2], splitData[23], splitData[29], t, jobID,function (resp) {
       valid_asb = resp.isASBExist;
       valid_FTTH = resp.isFTTHExist;
       tabCSite1Valid = valid_FTTH; // Update the global flag here
       console.log('tabCSite1Valid inside: ', tabCSite1Valid);

       // Move the for loop inside the callback function
       for (var i = 1; i < splitDatalen; i++) {
           console.log('tabCSite1Valid inside other one: ', tabCSite1Valid);
           //alert(splitData.length);
           row.insertCell(i);
           styleData = splitData[i + 1];
           if (typetable == "tabCEquip1" || typetable == "tabCSite1" || typetable == "tabCSBoundary1" || typetable == "tabLPcomm1" || typetable == "tabAddCardSplit1" || typetable == "tabDelEquip1" || typetable == "tabDelPath1" || typetable == "tabDelSB1" || typetable == "tabCPathConsumer1" || typetable == "tabCreateServiceOLT1") {
               if (tabCSite1Valid == false) {
                  tab.rows[p + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"valueZ\" name=\"" + checkboxname + "\" value=\"" + splitData[1] + "\" disabled/>";
                  styleData = "<span style='color: red'>" + splitData[i + 1] + "</span>";
                  console.log('Activated at FTTH');
               }
               if (splitData[3] != "ASB" && valid_asb == true) { //else && valid_FTTH == false
                  tab.rows[p + 1].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"valueZ\" name=\"" + checkboxname + "\" value=\"" + splitData[1] + "\" disabled/>";
                  styleData = "<span style='color: red'>" + splitData[i + 1] + "</span>";
                  console.log('Activated at ASB');
               }
           }
           tab.rows[p + 1].cells[i].innerHTML = styleData;
       }
   });
}
```

The above code ensures that the `loop` only executes after the `checkValidation` has finished processing, which should allow `tabCSite1Valid` to be `true` when the `for loop` is checking its value.

Also, if you need to use the **for loop** outside of the `checkValidation`, you might need to restructure your code to handle the asynchronous nature of the `checkValidation` function. This could involve using Promises or async/await to handle the asynchronous operations.

## Additional Code

Use a callback function to handle the result of the AJAX call. This way, you can ensure that the code execution waits for the AJAX call to complete before it proceed.

```
function getDetailsCheckJob(data, typetable, checkboxname,t) {
   // ... existing code ...

   for (var p = 0; p < Row.length - 1; p++) {
       // ... existing code ...

       if (typetable == "tabCEquip1") {
           checkValidation(splitData[2], splitData[28], splitData[29], t, jobID, function (resp) {
               valid_asb = resp.isASBExist;
               valid_FTTH = resp.isFTTHExist;
               handleValidationResult(typetable, splitData[1], checkboxname);
           });
       }

       else if (typetable == "tabCSite1") {
           checkValidation(splitData[2], splitData[23], splitData[29], t, jobID,function (resp) {
               valid_asb = resp.isASBExist;
               valid_FTTH = resp.isFTTHExist;
               tabCSite1Valid = valid_FTTH; // Update the global flag here
               handleValidationResult(typetable, splitData[1], checkboxname);
           });
       }

       // ... existing code ...
   }
}

function handleValidationResult(typetable, value, checkboxname) {
   // ... code to handle the validation result ...
   // This code should be moved from the loop in the getDetailsCheckJob function
   // to this new function.
}
```

Comment: I am using a very old .net, and it does not support async/await which is why im having problems, the call back function in the loop I am having trouble with as the rows are not coming out properly